# order by time, time in different columns same table

Tags: php, sql

Hi i making a table for "notifications" this have time for different issues on different columns for example (this are not all the values, but i think is enough to understand my issue)

```
id  | userid | itemid | messagesent | messageupdate |  messageseen |

int |  int   |   int  |    time()   |    time ()    |    time()    |
```

Then i need to order by time but those values are on different columns

```
qtres7 = $db->execute_query("select * from notifications where itemid =? OR userid=? ORDER BY messagesent asc",array($itemid,$userid));
```

Any ideas would be appreciated, i have found some info on order by but i can "mix" the results and order by recent to oldest no matter in wich column is time..

For example if i have 3 items where (0000001) its old and (00000003) its newer

```
id  | userid | itemid | messagesent | messageupdate |  messageseen | status | status2 |

1   |   12   |   120  |   0000001   |    -------    |    0000005   |    3   |    1    |
2   |   12   |   121  |   0000001   |    0000003    |    -------   |    2   |    1    |
3   |   12   |   122  |   0000003   |    -------    |    -------   |    1   |    2    |
```

For example in this example im doing my echo with for each inside for each i have

```
if ($userid = $actualuser && $status == 1) { echo $row style1}
if ($userid = $actualuser && $status == 2) { echo $row style2}
if ($userid = $actualuser && $status == 3) { echo $row style3}
if ($userid = $actualuser && $status2 == 1) { echo $row style4}
if ($userid = $actualuser && $status2 == 2) { echo $row style5}
```

I order this by messagesent - the result i get is this

Maybe i have an error because this is not an actual echo its a big huge table the one i have, trying to resume.

```
item 3 style 1 - 0000003 -------
item 3 style 5 - 0000003 -------
item 1 style 2 - 0000001 0000005
item 2 style 3 - 0000001 -------
item 1 style 4 - 0000001 0000005
item 2 style 4 - 0000001 -------
```

The problem is item 2 notification for message seen should be at top. like

```
item 1 style 2 - 0000001 0000005
item 1 style 4 - 0000001 0000005
item 3 style 1 - 0000003 -------
item 3 style 5 - 0000003 -------
item 2 style 3 - 0000001 -------
item 2 style 4 - 0000001 -------
```

Maybe my for each loop its the problem actually.. but this way i get all this working the problem is i can set a order bassed on time

bu, and i dont want to create a hole new table and change everything just for this order issue.

Comment: For example any sample output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a combination of a [union statement](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp) and group by clause.

```
select
  n.*,
  x.time
from (
  select
    x.id
    min( x.time ) as `time`
  from (
    select
      id,
      messagesent as `time`
    from notifications
    union all
    select
      id,
      messageupdate
    from notifications
    union all
    select
      id,
      messageseen
    from notifications
  ) x
  group by x.id
) x
left join notifications n on n.id = x.id
order by x.time
```

### Update

Alternatively, you could use MySQL's [least](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_least) and [greatest](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_greatest) functions to get the same effect:

```
select
  *
from notifications
order by least( messagesent, messageupdate, messageseen )
```

Comment: the problem is this just an example my table has like 15 values.. :( it would be a mess to do select for 15 columns 4 times ( i have 4 time vals) this look great anyway

Comment: Yeah, it's not pretty. I just found something though that will get the same effect, but won't be so ugly. You should checkout MySQL's least() function. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_least Maybe you could do something like: order by least(messagesent, messageupdate, messageseen)

Answer (score 1):

test it:

```
ORDER BY GREATEST(`messagesent`,`messageupdate `,`messageseen`)
```

Comment: very attractive , but i get syntax error.. is this for PHP as query sql?

Comment: excuse me Moncho, i have a mistake, you should use GREATEST function instead of MAX. i edited my post.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
"select * from notifications where itemid =? OR userid=? ORDER BY messagesent ASC, date_added DESC";
```